# App keeps Stopping Process: com.example.test101, PID: 7666 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I made an app which has 1 Activity and 2 Classes, 1 Main and 1 for my Database.
But whenever i run my app on my virtual phone it stops
it says its prolly the Activity thingy, but i dont know much about it i m very begginer to android

thnx in advance,
this is wat  i get in Log Cat

```
 Process: com.example.test101, PID: 7666
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test101/com.example.test101.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2843)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:159)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:675)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:692)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:214)
        at com.example.test101.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:20)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2831)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2020-10-17 21:57:56.379 7666-7666/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7666 SIG: 9
```

my code is 
**MAIN**

```
package com.example.test101;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    DBCreate db;

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_reg);
    EditText user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
    EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = new DBCreate(this);
        regUser();
    }

    public void regUser(){
        button.setOnKeyListener(
                new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                        boolean isInserted = db.insertData(user.getText().toString() ,pass.getText().toString());
                    if(isInserted){
                        Snackbar datI = Snackbar.make(constraintLayout, "Registered", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        datI.show();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        );
    }

    public void onReg(View view){

        if(user.getText().toString() == ""){
            Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(constraintLayout, "Please enter a valid username", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar1.show();
        }
        if(pass.getText().toString() == ""){
            Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(constraintLayout, "Please enter a valid password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar1.show();
        }
        if(user.getText().toString() == "ADMIN"){
            Snackbar snackbar1 = Snackbar.make(constraintLayout, "AAO PADHARO ADMIN SAAB", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            snackbar1.show();

            if(!(pass.getText().toString() == "ADMIN")){
                Snackbar snackbar2 = Snackbar.make(constraintLayout, "ADMIN SAAB PASSWORD TOH THIK DALO", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                snackbar2.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and 2nd

```
package com.example.test101;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class DBCreate extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "testoneoone.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "up";
    public static final String ID = "ID";
    public static final String NAME = "NAME";
    public static final String PASS = "PASS";


    public DBCreate(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, PASS TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean insertData( String name, String pass){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(PASS, pass);
        long res = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null,contentValues);
        return res != -1;
    }
}
```

**my activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="476dp"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="306dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_reg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="306dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_reg"
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:onClick="onReg"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="549dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="114dp"
        android:text="Already have an account?"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_reg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The first thing you do when you get a stack trace is look at the top line. If you don't understand it, look through the list until you see the line that says "Caused by..." You can't miss it -- it's unindented on purpose, so that you can find it easily. In your case, the line reads "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException" That's where you start your search. Always search online first before asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should not assign views references immediately, as the layout for the activity is not inflated at the moment. Defer it till `onCreate` method.

So,

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    DBCreate db;

    Button button;
    EditText user;
    EditText pass;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_reg);
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPassword);

        db = new DBCreate(this);
        regUser();
    }

// ... and so on
}
```